# Не работает функция mail на php в Openserver

Tags: php, email, openserver

Не работает отправка сообщений на почту php. В чем проблема?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image]

Comment: Что логи пишут?

Comment: Сам почтовый аккаунт возможно требует дополнительный разрешений. В настройках почты gmail это IMAP, а так же в настройках Google аккаунта это разрешение использовать аккаунт ненадежными устройствами.

Answer (score 1):

необходимо изменить настройку "Способ отправки почты" на "Отправлять почту через удаленный SMTP-сервер"